# Update Query Transaction Log

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

How can I find out what triggers are fired and what sql functions (system+user) are called or what views are updated and what all tables got updated when i fire a update query in ssms? Basically, I need an information about what all happened in the database when i fire an updated query. Is there any process to find out???

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Profiler may help with this. 
The accepted answer on this question linked by SchmitzIT will explain more: [How can I see which tables are changed in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836444/how-can-i-see-which-tables-are-changed-in-sql-server)